# How to create *-dev package from source?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, packaging

I want to install SILE Typesetter which depends on HarfBuzz (libharfbuzz-dev). The libharfbuzz-dev available from repositories is version 1.0.1 (released 2015), while the latest version available from HarfBuzz's website is 1.7.6 (released 2018). How can I create libharfbuzz-dev package from the available new source of HarfBuzz? Or how can I use the available source for building SILE, without creating the package libharfbuzz-dev?

---

I *basically* want to build SILE for myself but I certainly am interested in learning how to prepare a package (-dev as well as the regular package) for distribution.

Comment: @Melebius I have edited the question, adding the specific details. Please expand on how I can "compile and link the library" when building SILE?

Comment: The "harfbuzz (**1.7.6**-1ubuntu1)" build files are in Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic. You can add `deb src [url] cosmic main` to the sources.list and possibly build the harfbuzz_1.7.6..._amd64.deb packages with `$ apt-get -b source harfbuzz=1.7.6-1ubuntu1`

Comment: @Asim did Knud comment solve the problem? If no please update the question.